# How to write html image file source for thunderbird email signature on ubuntu

Tags: html, email, ubuntu, thunderbird

When I was sending emails from thunderbird on windows I had html signature that would be injected at the end of the email. That html contains come html code ( image tags ) that load images from local hard drive D: like this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/example"><img border="0" src="file://d:/mailsettings/facebook_logo.png"/></a>
```

Now I am working on Linux Mint ( Ubuntu distro ) and these images are located in my `home folder in Documents/mailsettings.` but I do not know how to target that path in my image source. Can someone help please ?

Comment: The [tag:signature] tag is reserved for *method* signatures.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double click on Image in Write mod and then a Cancel or OK then again double click and you will se a Image Location. Copy that end put in that htm .

Example:

```
data:image/png;filename=logika.png;base64,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
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission to thу folder from which you are accessing the img. Open you terminal and type this code:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/Documents/mailsettings/facebook_logo.png
```

After that press enter.

Try this:

```
~/Documents/mailsettings/
```

or

```
/home/*/Documents/mailsettings/ 
Where * => home folder
```